# What happens after I delete the ECR image after using it to create-image-version on Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr, amazon-sagemaker-studio

What happens after I delete the ECR image after using it to create-image-version on Sagemaker? Will I still be able to use the image?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? I believe the image will not get attached to the SageMaker Notebook/Studio kernel if the image is not available in ECR.